# p:datatable summary row calculation

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I have a `p:dataTable` pretty similar to the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/summaryRow.xhtml).
Unfortunatly, the showcase uses randomly generated values for the `p:summaryRow`.

Refering to the showcase, imagine the car had a price attribute.

**How would I sum up the price for the cars grouped by the specified column for displaying it in the summary row?**

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem with you and found correct usage from primefaces blog
[SummaryRow from primefaces forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16926)

this is some example show correct calculation for sum price, count...

Listener gets the group property which is the sortBy value which you can use to calculate totals or any other operation.

```
<p:summaryRow listener="#{backingBean.calculateTotal}"> 
                        <p:column colspan="3" style="text-align:right"> 
                            Total: 
                        </p:column> 

                        <p:column> 
                            #{backingBean.total}
                        </p:column> 
                    </p:summaryRow>

/* listener method in your bean */
public void calculateTotal(Object o) {
    this.total = 0.0d;
    String name = "";
    if(o != null) {
        if(o instanceof String) {
            name = (String) o;
            for(MyRowObject p : (List<MyRowObject>) dataTableModel.getWrappedData()) { // The loop should find the sortBy value rows in all dataTable data.
                switch(sortColumnCase) { // sortColumnCase was set in the onSort event
                    case 0:
                        if(p.getcolumn0data().getName().equals(name)) {
                            this.total += p.getcolumn0data().getValue();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if(p.getcolumn1data().getName().equals(name)) {
                            this.total += p.getcolumn1data().getValue();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is my solution:

```
<p:dataTable var="elem" value="#{unitSubStatusChart.resultList}" tableStyleClass="app-table-auto">
    <et:defaultPaginator />

    <p:column headerText="#{bundle['class']}" sortBy="#{elem.dtype}">
        <e:outputIconText icon="#{icons[elem.dtype]}" value="#{bundle[elem.dtype]}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{bundle['status']}" sortBy="#{elem.status}">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle[elem.status]}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{bundle['subStatus']}" sortBy="#{elem.subStatus}">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle[elem.subStatus]}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{bundle['count']}">
        <h:outputText value="#{elem.count}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:summaryRow listener="#{unitSubStatusChart.onSummaryRow}">
        <p:column colspan="3" style="text-align:right">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.total}:" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <!-- !!! NOTE THIS VALUE EXPRESSION !!! -->
            <h:outputText value="#{component.parent.attributes.total}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:summaryRow>
</p:dataTable>
```

and this is the listener:

```
public void onSummaryRow(Object filter)
{
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    ELResolver elResolver = elContext.getELResolver();

    DataTable table = (DataTable) UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(facesContext);

    UIColumn sortColumn = table.getSortColumn();
    ValueExpression expression = sortColumn.getValueExpression("sortBy");
    ValueReference reference = ValueExpressionAnalyzer.getReference(expression);
    String property = (String) reference.getProperty();

    int total = 0;
    List<?> rowList = (List<?>) table.getValue();
    for(Object row : rowList)
    {
        Object value = elResolver.getValue(elContext, row, property);
        if(filter.equals(value))
        {
            // THIS IS THE ONLY POINT TO CUSTOMIZE
            total += ((UnitResult) row).getCount();
        }
    }

    List<UIComponent> children = table.getSummaryRow().getChildren();
    UIComponent column = children.get(children.size() - 1);
    column.getAttributes().put("total", total);
}
```

This listener **has no external references**: it does not depend on previous onSort events/listeners and it doesn't need any field in the bean.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest a possible way to do this, may not be the most perfect, but i believe it will help.

Ther's the steps:

1 - Declare a class atribute to acumulate the total group value:

```
...
@Named(value = "myBean")
@YourScope

public class InscricaoBean implements Serializable {
...

//in this example i will use a int type

private int acumulatorAux = 0;
...
```

2 - Create a function to return the total value per group:

```
...
public int getAcumulatedValue() {
        int aux = acumulatorAux ;
        acumulatorAux = 0;
        return aux;
    }
...
```

3 - Create an method to acumulate values per group:

```
...
public void acumulateValue(int value)
    {
        acumulatorAux += value;
    }
...
```

4 - On JSF page, you need to call `acumulateValue` method for every row, something like:

```
...
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.getList()}" var="testVar">
       <p:column headerText="Header" sortBy="#{testVar.name}">
            #{inscricaoBean.acumulateValue(testVar.value)}
            <h:outputText value="#{testVar.name}" />
       </p:column>
 ...
```

5 - And next, you can have a `summaryRow` like:

```
    ...
    <p:summaryRow>
        <p:column colspan="1" style="text-align:right">
              <h:outputText value="Total:" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
              <h:outputText value="#{inscricaoBean.getAcumulatedValue()}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:summaryRow>
    ...
```

Well, this is a gross way to acomplish this task. I think you can improve, but it was the first think when i see your question.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Using multiple columns in summaryRow that's the only one working for me.

Answer (score 0):

by using Lambda expression it works in java 1.7 with EL 3.0
n your JSF it would be like this :

```
 <p:summaryRow>
  <p:column colspan="3" style="text-align:right">
   <h:outputText value="Total:" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{car.stream().map(item->item.price).sum()}">
     <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" />
    </h:outputText>
  </p:column>
 </p:summaryRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to pass the datatable's `sortBy="#{car.brand}"` value within the `p:summaryRow` into a backing method that uses a stream to compute price subtotal.

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtSummaryRowView.cars}" sortBy="#{car.brand}">
        <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{car.id}">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Year" sortBy="#{car.year}">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Brand" sortBy="#{car.brand}">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Color" sortBy="#{car.color}">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:summaryRow>
            <p:column colspan="3" style="text-align:right">
                <h:outputText value="Total:" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{dtSummaryRowView.brandSubtotal(car.brand)}">
                    <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
        </p:summaryRow>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

.

```
public double brandSubtotal(String brand) {
    return cars.stream().filter(c -> c.getBrand().equals(brand)).mapToDouble(c -> c.getPrice()).sum();
}
```

Another approach is to use the listener in `p:summaryRow` to set a backing bean attribute and then use getter to display the attribute.

```
    <p:summaryRow listener="#{dtSummaryRowView.computeSubtotal(car.brand)}">
        <p:column colspan="3" style="text-align:right">
            <h:outputText value="Total:" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{dtSummaryRowView.subTotal}">
                <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:summaryRow>
```

.

```
public void computeSubtotal(String brand) {
    subTotal = cars.stream().filter(c -> c.getBrand().equals(brand)).mapToDouble(c -> c.getPrice()).sum();
}

public double getSubTotal () {
    return subTotal ;
}
```